# check if date is not equal to NA or string and date< datetime(2000,01,01) replace date with NaT in pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

```
def checkDF():
    list1=[{'BatchNumber':'b1','Reason':'r1.1','value':1,'date':datetime(1700,01,01)},
           {'BatchNumber':'b1','Reason':'r1.2','value':1,'date':'NA'},
           {'BatchNumber':'b2','Reason':'r2','value':2,'date':datetime(2001,03,04)}]
    df=pd.DataFrame(list1)

df.loc[df['date']!='NA' & df['date'] < datetime(2000,01,01),'date']="NaT"

if __name__=='__main__':
    checkDF()
```

I want to replace date column values when date is NA and less than 2000, but i am not able to compare these two conditions together in pandas

Answer (score 0):

I think need first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert non datetime to `NaT` (it is not string, but missing value):

```
list1=[{'BatchNumber':'b1','Reason':'r1.1','value':1,'date':pd.datetime(1700,1,1)},
           {'BatchNumber':'b1','Reason':'r1.2','value':1,'date':'NA'},
           {'BatchNumber':'b2','Reason':'r2','value':2,'date':pd.datetime(2001,3,4)}]
df  = pd.DataFrame(list1)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), errors='coerce')
df.loc[df['date'] < '2000-01-01', 'date']=np.nan
#if want check not NaNs
#df.loc[(df['date'].notnull()) & (df['date'] < pd.datetime(2000,1,1)),'date']=np.nan
print (df)
  BatchNumber Reason       date  value
0          b1   r1.1        NaT      1
1          b1   r1.2        NaT      1
2          b2     r2 2001-03-04      2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [{'BatchNumber':'b1','Reason':'r1.1','value':1,'date':datetime(1700,1,1)},
           {'BatchNumber':'b1','Reason':'r1.2','value':1,'date':'NA'},
           {'BatchNumber':'b2','Reason':'r2','value':2,'date':datetime(2001,3,4)}]

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)

# Create a function to represent your change
def f(x):
    if (isinstance(x, datetime) and x.year < 2000) or x == 'NA':
        return pd.NaT
    else:
        return x

# Apply this function to only the date column
df['date'] = df.date.map(f)

# Output
  BatchNumber Reason       date  value
0          b1   r1.1        NaT      1
1          b1   r1.2        NaT      1
2          b2     r2 2001-03-04      2
```

**Notes**:

- Can't use 01 to represent 1 in the dates (raises a `SyntaxError`)
- `NA` in your data is a text value and not `numpy.nan` (the actual `NA`) hence we check for the string `'NA'`

Comment: @shubham-thagunna Does this answer your question?